# MongoMapper: Get all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Does anyone know of an easy way to fetch the class names of all models that have `MongoMapper::Document` included?

The `MongoMapper` class doesn't appear to have the equivalent of `ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses`.

The best I can come up with is using `MongoMapper.database.collection_names` and some `ObjectSpace` hacks.

A further complication is that I have modules (subfolders) in the `app/models` folder. So, `class DS::Thingy` is in my `apps/models/ds/thingy.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
class MongoModels
  def self.all
    @@models ||= []
  end
end

module MongoMapper
  module Document
    def self.included(klass) 
      MongoModels.all << klass
    end
  end
end
```

then MongoModels::all would return an Array of models.

MongoMapper's document.rb does:

```
included do
  extend Plugins
  extend Translation
end
```

So you might need to replicate that.

Comment: Cool, yea I like it. I'll modify that a bit, but the basic idea is a good one, thanks!